# net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE while doing POST request with axios react

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, post, axios

I am trying to post some data to my server however i am getting this error "POST http://localhost:5001/api/... net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

```
        axios.post(
        `http://localhost:5001/api/MedicalRecords/${this.state.patientID}/Appointments`,
        {data : this.state.medicalRecord},
        {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }
    ).then(response => console.log(response)).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Where should I search for mistake? Is this backend(ASP.NET), frontend(react) or axios problem?

Swagger lets me to try my methods out, and post method on the swagger page is pesponding 200, so i think the key is hidden somewhere in axios configuration.